# USB Mass storage driver as CDROM in Windows & MAC

Tags: linux, macos, kernel, compact-disc

I am in the process of enumerating a Hybrid ISO image which will show up as CDROM in Windows & MAC and encountered with the following problem.

Hybrid ISO image is created with the following options and inserted the driver as `"insmod g_mass_storage.ko file=/hybrid.iso"
mkisofs -input-charset iso8859-1 -J -r -hide-rr-moved -joliet-long -o hybrid.iso TestDir/`

`"insmod g_mass_storage.ko file=/hybrid.iso"`
With the above options:
Image Shows up as CDROM in MAC but not in Windows (It shows up as "Removable Disk" and on double click,  it prompts to format the disk even though the image works in MAC)

`"insmod g_mass_storage.ko file=/hybrid.iso cdrom=1"`
With CDROM=1 option, it works in Windows but on MAC, i get the pop message as "The disk you inserted was not readable by this Computer" Ignore/Eject".

I am not sure where to start with to fix this issue. Should it be fixed in the the way I create the ISO image/Mass storage driver/Windows/MAC?